# __getitem__ for a list vs a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, magic-methods

The **Dictionary** `__getitem__` method does not seem to work the same way as it does for **List**, and it is causing me headaches.  Here is what I mean:

If I subclass **list**, I can overload `__getitem__` as:

```
class myList(list):
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        if isinstance(index,int):
            #do one thing
        if isinstance(index,slice):
            #do another thing
```

If I subclass **dict**, however, the `__getitem__` does not expose *index*, but *key* instead as in:

```
class myDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        #Here I want to inspect the INDEX, but only have access to key!
```

So, my question is how can I intercept the *index* of a dict, instead of just the *key*?

Example use case:

```
a = myDict()
a['scalar'] = 1  # Create dictionary entry called 'scalar', and assign 1
a['vector_1'] = [1,2,3,4,5]  # I want all subsequent vectors to be 5 long
a['vector_2'][[0,1,2]] = [1,2,3]  # I want to intercept this and force vector_2 to be 5 long
print(a['vector_2'])
[1,2,3,0,0]
a['test']  # This should throw a KeyError
a['test'][[0,2,3]]  # So should this
```

Comment: `key` and `index` are just *local names*; you can use `supercalifragilisticexpialidocious` for all Python cares.

Comment: Dictionaries **have no order**, there is no index.

Comment: They implement the same way because you call them the same way: `dict[0]` is looking up the value for key `0`, and `list[0]` is looking up the value in the first index. `dict` doesn't have an order, so you probably want to iterate over `.keys()`

Comment: `a['vector_2'][0,1,2]` does not conform with `a['vector_1'] = [1,2,3,4,5]`; the former varies on 4 dimensions (str -> int -> int -> int) but the latter on 2 (str -> int).  I can get to the 5 `vector_1` as `a['vector_1'][4]`, but the 2 in vector_2 would be something like `a['vector_2'][0, 1, 2][1]`.  It's not clear at all what the shape of your data should be.

Comment: @IfLoop: I have updated my buggy indexing to include internal []'s.  Sorry.

Comment: your indexing was fine, at least it means (almost) the same thing before and after the edit.  Can you elaborate on what problem you're trying to solve?  If I printed out the contents of `a`, once it's got a good amount of data in it, what would it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries have no order; there is no index to pass in; this is why Python can use the same syntax (`[..]`) and the same magic method (`__getitem__`) for both lists and dictionaries.

When you index a dictionary on an integer like `0`, the dictionary treats that like any other key:

```
>>> d = {'foo': 'bar', 0: 42}
>>> d.keys()
[0, 'foo']
>>> d[0]
42
>>> d['foo']
'bar'
```

Chained indexing applies to return values; the expression:

```
a['vector_2'][0, 1, 2]
```

is executed as:

```
_result = a['vector_2']  # via a.__getitem__('vector_2')
_result[0, 1, 2]         # via _result.__getitem__((0, 1, 2))
```

so if you want *values* in your dictionary to behave in a certain way, you must return objects that support those operations.